# How do I add GoogleAnalytics header snippet in WordPress?

Tags: html, headers, google-analytics

I am not sure where exactly I navigate to add the analytics code once so it gets to all the WordPress pages.

Do I change the HTML manually or can I do this from WordPress somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Paste to the closing  `</body>`tag ... Look for the footer.php file in your theme template on your hosting

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to edit the theme file directly. It is best practice to use some sort of plugin.

[Monster Insight](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/) is one of the best available in the market. It is available in the WordPress repository.